# Surjectivity of compact operator after perturbation

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Assume $T$ is a compact operator on Hilbert space $H$ and $k>0$. If we can show $I+k^2T$ is injective, does that imply it is  surjective as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the Fredholm alternative, which says if $T$ is compact, $\lambda \neq 0$ and $(T-\lambda I)x=0$ has no nontrivial solution, then $(T-\lambda I)x=b$ has a unique solution for each $b$.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!